# which should come first creating a django user or a stripe payments charge?

Tags: django, stripe-payments

I am using Django and stripe checkout.  When someone new comes to the site, wanting to join and pay by credit card, I need to create a new user (ie setup a user name and password) as well as charge them (via stripe's API).

From a code and UX perspective, which should come first? Or, better,  can I do both in one step?

Note: various web tutorials discuss these separately but never together.

Comment: Creating a customer and saving a card (payment_method) needs to be done in two Stripe API calls and currently there is no way you could do it in one. Saying all that, I would recommend to create a Stripe Customer first and map internally to your own users and then choose to add the card to the customer as user might not want to save the card at all for one time transactions. If they want to save the card, you could then attach the card to the customer. The next time when your user logs in, you check if the cusotmer exists already and skip the customer creation part.

Comment: Not the stripe customer, the django user